# Designing posts: state machine

Tags: rust, state-machine

In the [Object-Oriented Design Pattern Implementation chapter](http://rust-lang.github.io/book/second-edition/ch17-03-oo-design-patterns.html) of the [second edition of *The Rust Programming Language*](http://rust-lang.github.io/book/second-edition/), the basic code structure is given and it suggests trying to add features:

> This implementation is easy to extend to add more functionality. Here
>   are some changes you can try making to the code in this section to see
>   for yourself what it's like to maintain code using this pattern over
>   time:
>
> - Only allow adding text content when a post is in the `Draft` state
> - Add a `reject` method that changes the post's state from `PendingReview` back to `Draft`
> - Require two calls to `approve` before changing the state to `Published`

Please critique my approach:

```
struct Post {
    content: String
}

struct DraftPost {
    content: String
}

struct PendingPost {
    content: String,
    approvals: u32

}

impl Post {
    fn new() -> DraftPost {
        DraftPost { content: String::new() }
    }

    fn content(&self) -> &str {
        &self.content
    }
}

impl DraftPost {
    fn req_review(self) -> PendingPost {
        PendingPost {
            content: self.content,
            approvals: 0
        }
    }

    fn add_text(&mut self, content: &str) {
        self.content.push_str(content);
    }
}

enum PublishResult {
    PendingPost(PendingPost),
    Post(Post)
}

impl PendingPost {
    fn approve(&mut self) {
        self.approvals += 1;
    }
    fn reject(self) -> DraftPost {
        DraftPost { content: self.content }
    }
    fn publish(self) -> PublishResult {
        if self.approvals > 1 {
            PublishResult::Post(Post{content: self.content})
        } else {
            PublishResult::PendingPost(self)
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn publish_workflow() {
        let mut draft = Post::new();
        draft.add_text("ashish first post");
        let mut pending = draft.req_review();
        pending.approve();
        pending.approve();
        let publish = pending.publish();
        match publish {
            PublishResult::Post(p) => assert_eq!(p.content(),
                                                 "ashish first post"),
            _ => assert!(false)
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn reject_workflow() {
        let mut draft = Post::new();
        draft.add_text("ashish first post");
        let pending = draft.req_review();
        let mut again_draft = pending.reject();
        again_draft.add_text(".. after first one..");
    }

    #[test]
    fn two_approvals_workflow() {
        let mut draft = Post::new();
        draft.add_text("ashish first post");
        let mut pending = draft.req_review();
        pending.approve();
        match pending.publish() {
            PublishResult::PendingPost(_) => assert!(true),
            _ => assert!(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, everything seems fine. Some minor nits and suggestions:

1. Stylistically, you should have:

   - trailing commas
   - spaces on struct literals (`Post { content: self.content }`
2. `PublishResult` makes me think it's a type alias of [`std::result::Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html). I'd advocate for picking a different name.
3. Instead of matching in your tests and having the not-very-useful `assert!(true)` and `assert!(false)`, add some helper methods to `PublishResult` to convert to an expected variant. This is a common pattern for this style of enum. Then you can `expect` with text in your tests
4. Dnt ndlssly abbr mthds (Don't needlessly abbreviate methods). Call it `request_review` instead of `req_review`.
5. It's strange to have a test (`reject_workflow`) with no assertions. I don't think anything's *wrong* with it, as it's testing the methods and types, it's just a bit implicit.

```
struct Post {
    content: String,
}

struct DraftPost {
    content: String,
}

struct PendingPost {
    content: String,
    approvals: u32,
}

impl Post {
    fn new() -> DraftPost {
        DraftPost { content: String::new() }
    }

    fn content(&self) -> &str {
        &self.content
    }
}

impl DraftPost {
    fn request_review(self) -> PendingPost {
        PendingPost {
            content: self.content,
            approvals: 0,
        }
    }

    fn add_text(&mut self, content: &str) {
        self.content.push_str(content);
    }
}

enum PublishResult {
    PendingPost(PendingPost),
    Post(Post),
}

impl PublishResult {
    fn into_pending_post(self) -> Option<PendingPost> {
        use PublishResult::*;
        match self {
            PendingPost(v) => Some(v),
            _ => None,
        }
    }

    fn into_post(self) -> Option<Post> {
        use PublishResult::*;
        match self {
            Post(v) => Some(v),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}

impl PendingPost {
    fn approve(&mut self) {
        self.approvals += 1;
    }
    fn reject(self) -> DraftPost {
        DraftPost { content: self.content }
    }
    fn publish(self) -> PublishResult {
        if self.approvals > 1 {
            PublishResult::Post(Post { content: self.content })
        } else {
            PublishResult::PendingPost(self)
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn publish_workflow() {
        let mut draft = Post::new();
        draft.add_text("ashish first post");
        let mut pending = draft.request_review();
        pending.approve();
        pending.approve();
        let post = pending.publish().into_post().expect("not a post");
        assert_eq!(post.content(), "ashish first post");
    }

    #[test]
    fn reject_workflow() {
        let mut draft = Post::new();
        draft.add_text("ashish first post");
        let pending = draft.request_review();
        let mut again_draft = pending.reject();
        again_draft.add_text(".. after first one..");
    }

    #[test]
    fn two_approvals_workflow() {
        let mut draft = Post::new();
        draft.add_text("ashish first post");
        let mut pending = draft.request_review();
        pending.approve();
        pending
            .publish()
            .into_pending_post()
            .expect("Not a pending post");
    }
}
```

Comment: Question: stylistically, is it better to declare a `struct` and its `impl` together, or declare the `struct`s together and the `impl`s together?

Comment: @DanAmbrogio I prefer (and think is general consensus) to do struct, impls, struct, impls, .... I don't know that I've seen it put in words anywhere, but I tend to do [1] type definition [2] inherent methods (`impl Type {...}`) [3] trait implementations (`impl Foo for Type {...}`) then repeat.